# How to split a data into k-folds NOT randomly in Python

Tags: python, cross-validation, k-fold

My data contains groups (individual people). Every observation in the data is the individual's age, starting from 16 up until death, which varies for every individual. For cross-validation I need to split the data into k-folds, but I feel I should not be doing it randomly. I'd want to split the data by groups (individuals' lifetimes).

I have grouped my data previously, but how do I make sure my k-fold cross validation will do the split by group instead of randomly?

```
grouped = data.groupby('id')
lifetimes_list = grouped.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called *stratified cross-validation*. For a discussion of when it might be a good idea, see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation) on the appropriately named stackexchange site.

In Python, you can do it most conveniently with scikit-learn's [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) class.